# Quartz jub to run at specified time or as soon as process/server is up?

Tags: java, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler, jobs

If batch jobs(scheduled through quartz scheduler) is scheduled at 9 am in the morning. But assume mine job process is running started at 10.am. Say process is up at 10 am. What I want is if somehow job is not run for that day(like in this case as process/server was down at 9 am), it should be triggered as soon as process is up . Do i need to do any configuration for this or it has to be handled manually through programmatic approach ?

Answer (score 0):

This is just for reference  to use repeatCount and repeatInterval you can set this as per your framework, I dont know this may be helpful answer to you or not

```
 <bean id="whateverTriggerAtStartupTime" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="whateverJob"/>
        <property name="repeatCount" value="0"/>
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="10"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Quartz how to handle misfires. [This site](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html) has many examples about how to do that. You can also check [Quartz's official documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html) where they explain the different misfire instructions available for each trigger type.